# Which Expansions and Adventures will rotate out of Standard with "Knights of the Frozen Throne"?

Tags: hearthstone

Currently in Standard are:

- Un'Goro
- Mean Street of Gadgetzan
- Whispers of the old Gods
- One Night in Karazan
- Classic

I asume ONIK and WOTOG will rotate out. is that correct?

Comment: Since this is happening in the future, I don't think this is something we can answer, and in fact, have a specific off-topic reason for.

Comment: 1. how is this off-topic? 2. as you can see below. there is a definitve answer.

Comment: 1. It's about what will happen in the future.  We don't allow questions about the future of the industry; it's literally an off-topic reason.  2. Answerability doesn't really come into play; it makes for an incredibly poor metric for whether or not questions can stick around.

Comment: If you want to keep this, I'd suggest editing it to ask about how Hearthstone's expansion rotation works; that's objective, not asking about the future, and you can derive your answer from that information.

Comment: @Frank It's about _announced_ content, so it's not really off-topic.  The information is definitely out there.  The question doesn't ask for speculation or anything; so I don't see how it's really off topic (though I don't think it's a great question either).

Comment: @JMac Announced content is the *worst kind*.  That means we have absolutely nothing but the developer's word to go on, and is one of the main reasons we deny it.  Like I said, just because a question can be answered *doesn't mean we allow it*.  Asking about the future of the industry is off-topic.  It doesn't matter one single bit whether it's answerable or not.

Comment: @Frank Where do you see that "Asking about the future of the industry is off-topic"?  The [on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page discusses **"Speculation"**, but not all questions about future releases involve speculation.  In this particular case, Blizzard has already been clear on the Standard rotation format _and_ made a statement about this particular patch regarding the rotation format.  Very different than speculation.

Comment: @JMac If it's not playable, **it is speculation**.  Developers change things **all the time**.  XBone always online, anyone?  The point is, we can't trust what developers have said, any more than we can trust rumors or journalists.  Nice, simple rule: if you're asking about something you can't actually play yet, it's off-topic.  Period.

Comment: @Frank Can you provide any source on that?  I disagree that it's "speculation" to ask about information already released by the developer and made clear for a long time.  By that same logic, could we say any game advice is "speculation" because the developers are free to patch their games at any time?

Comment: @JMac The difference is one is playable, the other is not.  See [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/), [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5539/), and especially relevent, [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7903/).  We have a long history of closing questions about unreleased, but announced, features, consoles, games, whathaveyou.  If it's not playable, don't ask about it here.

Comment: I don't think you should compare games/console with "seasons"

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW While in this case it is unlikely, Blizzard can potentially decide to change the rules of Standard decks, like only allowing the N previous expansions instead of basing it on the M previous years. We don't know if a promise will be kept, and we have decided to take a blanket ban on ALL promises, even the promise is based around company policy (because the policy can change before that). Asking about the current policy is fine, because the policy is useful right now.

Comment: @Frank Woah, woah.  There is nothing speculative about the Standard format.  That'd be like saying there's speculation on what sets would be included in MTG Standard.  It has a set-in-stone definition and there is definitely a correct answer.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann And that's why I'm saying that's what this question needs to be edited to.  Ask about the expansion rotation; that's objective, can draw on expertise, and will answer the underlying question.  Asking what will happen in the future is speculation, regardless of the confidence of the answers.

Comment: Frank is correct in this situation. This is unreleased content. Although the answer is correct and we all know it, we do not allow questions based on unreleased content. Even though the odds are very low that this system will change and the answer will remain correct after the content is released, this question is off topic until that time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cards don't rotate out EVERY expansion, but rather the first expansion of a given year. so no cards will rotate out with KotFT, nor with the planned fall expansion of this year. The first time cards will rotate out is with the Spring expansion of 2018.

Source: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Standard_format